# Separate regressions for each group vs combined and non-interacted regressions

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Let $Y$ be the dependent variable, $X$ be the independent variable of interest, and $G_i$ be the group indicator with $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Both $X$ and $Y$ are continuous. To study the association between $X$ and $Y$, one approach would be to run separate regressions for each group, i.e.,
$$Y=\beta_0+\beta_{1i}X+\epsilon.$$

In the spirit of [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17110/should-i-run-separate-regressions-for-every-community-or-can-community-simply-b), would it also make sense to estimate one regression for all five groups as follows?
$$Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 X_1+\beta_2 X_2+\beta_3 X_3+\beta_4 X_4+\beta_5 X_5+\epsilon$$
In the equation above, $X_i=X$ when the observation belongs to group $i$ and 0 otherwise.

I understand the first and the second approach differs in the assumptions regarding $\epsilon$. Putting that aside, would it be appropriate to interpret $\beta_1$...$\beta_5$ as the association between $X$ and $Y$ for group $i\in\{1,...,5\}$?

Suppose I perform a Wald test of coefficient equality, e.g., testing if $\beta_1=\beta_2$, can I interpret this test as testing whether the association between $X$ and $Y$ differs between groups $1$ and $2$?

Comment: It seems your Q is answered in the linked post? You must interact the group variable $G$ with X, other posts with this advice is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373890/separate-models-vs-flags-in-the-same-model/373909#373909